# Tracking an ebay token

Tags: token, ebay-api

I have a custom ebay connector, and it currently operates using a Token, and is able to pull in orders from the client's seller account using the Trading API.

The programmer that wrote the majorit of the app has left, and I can't determine if the token is associated with the production keys in my developer app. I can't see a report or list of tokens attached or anything.

How can I determine if the token is operating under my developer account? The token appears to be the only credential used to link the system up.

Also, I don't actually know what the developer did to create the token in the first place. The app is not public, it doesn't appear on the client's Applications or Subscriptions, how does one control the auth tokens that they have in ebay when they are allowing access from private apps?

Thanks for any help. The client is hitting API limits and I need to get the program through compatible app chcking.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

you can use this request to check the token validity

GetTokenStatusRequest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetTokenStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>$auth_token</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<ErrorLanguage>en_GB</ErrorLanguage>
<MessageID>$messageID</MessageID>
<Version>$api_version</Version>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetTokenStatusRequest>​
```

Or you can do FetchToken request check API call list [here](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/)

Comment: Doesn't appear to tell me what AppId it's linked to. I've changed key anyhow, so if my usage report errors, I can confidently tell ebay that their developer area has a fault in it!